# ggplot() increase spacing between tick marks and y axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I insert white space in between the `-` tick marks on my y-axis, and the `%` symbol for the different values?

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = prop)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

They currently look like this:

```
40.0%-
35.0%-
30.0%-
25.0%-
```

And I prefer they look like this:

```
40.0% -
35.0% -
30.0% -
25.0% -
```

Comment: `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r=10)))` (use whatever you want besides `10`)

Answer (score 0):

Try tweaking the theme around. Here's an attempt:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = prop)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  theme(axis.ticks.length =unit(1.5,"mm"),axis.ticks.y = element_line(size=0.5))
```